# MSChart: Remove gaps between series

Tags: c#, mschart

I am using MSchart Control to represent data graphically. Could you please assist me with the following problem: I put two series to the chart area but there is an evident gap between them. How can I remove it? Consider an example below. There are two series (orange and purple). I would be glad to remove everything between them so they are placed in a continuous manner. If it does matter, X-axis is actually time. Thanks in advance.

![image]

Comment: What's the highest X value for orange, and the lowest X value for purple? If there's a big gap between those, shouldn't there also be a big gap on the chart?

Comment: Assume the following relationship holds "1 cell = 1 day". So, there are 7 cells between that series which equals to 7 days. If every day are to be displayed, then, yes, because of the continuity of time it must be a gap between that series but I would like to remove that gap. So, if the highest X value for orange is "01/01/2011" and the lowest X value for purple is "01/08/2011" I would like my graph looks like "01/08/2011" follows "01/01/2011".

Answer (score 1):

Series class has an IsXValueIndexed property. When you set it to true, the series data points will be plotted according to their order in the series rather than plotting them according to their time values. Be sure to sort the Series so that all data points are in proper order.

Comment: But if there are several series (like in the example above), I cannot set IsXValuIndexed property to true for all of them as it will raise an exception because series are not aligned. Could you please be more concrete in what you have in mind. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @TruLa, well, as far as I know theres no way to do that, unless you combine both series into one.